# How to avoid users from downloading videos in my website?

Tags: security, video

I have a site with Joomla, and I want run online training in my website,that users just can watch videos online, and they can't download the videos.
Is there any way to do this? How?

Comment: Pretty sure it can't be done... People always find ways to download them anyway.

Comment: If the user really wanted to, they could simply record the screen while the video is playing.  Either you let users access your content or you don't, you can't have it both ways.

Comment: Totally agree with above comments!!!

Comment: From the server perspective, there is no difference between download and playing. It cant restrict one and not the other, because they are the same thing. The browser decides whether to save it to a file or render it to the screen. What you are looking for is DRM.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different approaches you could explore.

A number of organisations provide DRM extensions for joomla - these are designed to allow you protect your video content and are presumably well integrated with Joomla (I have not used them myself). Some may require browser plugins, which is a disadvantage as users often are reluctant to download and install new plugins:

- http://extensions.joomla.org/browse/new/extension/multimedia/multimedia-players/vdocipher-protect-video
- http://www.drm-x.com/DRM_Joomla_Plugin.aspx

Alternatively, you can host your videos on a service that provides DRM protection and integrate this into your site. One example which does integrate with Joomla and which should avoid plugins as much as possible is:

- https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/content-protection-drm & http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/publishing-video-cloud-players-joomla

You will need to look at costs, any issues with plugins etc to choose which is bets for your application.